# ntpd config optimization

Tags: startup, ntp, ntpd

I have an embedded Linux system *without* RTC, so it (currently) boots with thinking it's Jan, 1st 1970.

I have `ntpd` installed and started as:

```
/usr/bin/ntpd -g
```

with a pretty standard `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.pool.ntp.org iburst

restrict default nomodify nopeer noquery limited kod
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict [::1]
```

Unfortunately this takes a looong time (sometimes >120s) to achieve lock (i.e.: a peer flagged with `*` in `ntpq -nc peers`).

What further options (if any) could I use to shorten as much as possible sync time?

Related question: what is a reasonable sync time (assuming a reasonable network connection with ~16ms `ping` time to `0.pool.ntp.org`)?

Note: I *did* read `man 8 ntpd` and `man 5 ntp.conf`, but I'm pretty confused and I would like expert advice.

### Update:

Given the comments I think I need to elaborate my use-case:

1. My embedded Linux system does *not* have a RTC, so it wakes up at Jan 1st 1970.
2. I start `ntpd` from sysV initialization scripts as `start-stop-daemon -S -q -x /usr/sbin/ntpd -- -g`
3. I need to know when system time is "reasonably  close" (I can accept error of several seconds, not in the "minutes" range).
4. Network may be either wired or WiFi (or both), so it may take a substantial amount of time for it to get up.
5. Even when LAN is up-and-running I may have problems accessing Time Servers due to connectivity, NAT or firewalling; this means waiting a fixed amount of time won't work (even if I can `ping` the server!).
6. I can have "correct" time by means different from `ntp` (e.g.: user explicitly sets date&time, possibly with huge error!).

My aim is to get info, as soon as possible, if current time was retrieved from `ntp` server (so it can be "trusted") or not.  As said I do not need sub-second precision, but I need to know "for sure" if and when minute is correct, as soon as possible, assuming net is working, of course).

Comment: Did you consider to use ntp pool near to you? `server 0.it.pool.ntp.org`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Generally, using the main pool _should_ automatically select servers close by.

Comment: Have you try to run `ntpdate` at startup of the system to force time sync?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I could do that, but I sincerely doubt I'll get a faster ping time over a WiFi / NATted connection. I tested on a live system: ping times are very similar (and randomly changing due to pool selection). I'm looking for a more stable solution.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: `ntpdate` executable is deprecated and (if I understand it correctly!) `ntpd -g` should "mimic" it (if also `-q` is given it will also exit). Did I miss something?

Comment: Is the issue that the stepping that `ntpd -g` does is too inaccurate? Are you in need of correct to-the-millisecond timekeeping within the first few minutes after the machine is booted?

Comment: @Kusalananda: I only need a "roughly accurate" (i.e.: <10s) synchronization, but I need to know if that was achieved (I currently issue a `ntpq -nc peers` and parse the  output to see if there's an entry flagged with `*`). My problem is this takes a long time.

Comment: Have you ever observed that the initial stepping is less than 10s accurate? I'd be highly surprised if it was more than a second or two off. The "lock on" would, IMHO, not be terribly important. It just means that it's done a few queries to a particular server that seems well-behaved. That will, by necessity, take some time.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I seem unable to explain myself :( Please let me rephrase: after I issue a `start-stop-daemon -S -q -x /usr/sbin/ntpd -- -g` (which returns immediately) how can I detect `ntpd` is "reasonably sure" it has the correct time? what can/should I poll? Obviously waiting a fixed amount of time is not enough (e.g.: net could be down).